# Noisy water system in GE Profile fridge

Tags: water

My GE Profile refrigerator's water dispenser started making a noise when drawing water and I replaced the filter with the bypass insert. Now the noise has stopped but no water comes out. What could have caused the rattling sound that has now stopped and why can't I get water with the bypass in?

Comment: why do you need a bypass insert?

Comment: Is your bypass the right model. The bypass should tell the fridge to allow water or not.

Answer (score 0):

There is a switch around where filter bypass goes a lot of off brand filters wont work and bypass has to in correctly. those filter housing has a habit of getting clogged.